# Pushing new content to emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-emulator, adb

English is not my mother language

I have a problem with Unity.
I connect my Nexus 5 to computer and try to build and run my app to my phone (USB debugging in enabled).  But it saying "Pushing new content to device emulator 5554". When I disconnect and reconnect phone or clicked "end task" adb.exe in Task Manager it works

How to avoid this problem? Can I delete emulator?

Thanks.

Comment: "English is not my mother language" <= a self-affirming statement :) ..... (it's either "mother tongue" or "native language"). Anyhow, I'm not experienced with Unity + mobile but I suppose you'll need to set the deployment target, probably in the Build Settings dialog.

Comment: be sure to have android ndk installed and proper path setted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem. 
The solution, at least in my case, was very easy.

1. disconnect your device fron the PC or laptop
2. in your device, change from MTP to PTP protocols
3. connect again your device to your PC or laptop
4. try again the 'build and run', the problem should disappear.

I hope this can be useful for others.